# Comparing reference classes objects in R

Tags: oop, r, class, reference, comparison

I recently started using [reference classes](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/methods/ReferenceClasses). At some point I would like to test whether two variables point at the same instance, or at different ones.

However, could not find any appropriate operator or function for this purpose:

- `==` doesn't apply to objects,
- `identical` and `all.equal` just consider values, so won't be able to discriminate between two identical but distinct instances,
- same thing for the package [`compare`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/compare/)

If anyone knows how to do that, I'd be much obliged!

Thanks

Comment: It's "reference classes" not "class references".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`identical` does work.  Using the `mEdit` class from the `?ReferenceClasses` page, try

```
xMat <- matrix(1:12,4,3)
xx <- mEdit$new(data = xMat)
yy <- mEdit$new(data = xMat)
identical(xx, xx)
identical(xx, yy)
```

Comment: thanks, my bad!  
actually, i had tried `identical` with some lists:  
`x <- list(1,2,3)`  
`y <- list(1,2,3)`  
`identical(x,y) # true`  
list are R objects, right? so shouldn't this work, too?  
(my problem is solved, this question is just out of curiosity)

Comment: The internal `identical` method works differently for different types of variable.  Most things should be compared by value unless they contain an environment (like reference classes do).